# What is the difference between right clicking and Shift+Ins to paste text in PuTTY?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, putty, copy-paste

What is the difference between right clicking and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd>  to paste text in PuTTY?

I have noticed that for long text, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ins</kbd> to paste the entire text whereas right clicking paste often chops the text as shown below. Why?

[image]

Here is the text I was copying (from http://www.lipsum.com/, generated with 1000 words) using right click:  from time to time the text is cut (the entire text was copied correctly 3 times and was cut 2 times):

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque cursus sed nibh sed ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec vulputate lacus. Fusce vitae odio in nulla tempus maximus. Curabitur condimentum et augue sit amet laoreet. Fusce lobortis massa sed tellus vulputate, vel malesuada eros vulputate. Vivamus eu enim id sem tempor congue sit amet at eros. Pellentesque luctus enim libero, vel tristique tellus congue eget. Vivamus at nisl venenatis, commodo tellus a, varius purus. In vel dolor vitae nibh pharetra accumsan. Sed volutpat laoreet ipsum quis mattis.

Nulla eu purus justo. Sed massa dui, convallis eu elit vitae, maximus vehicula sem. Maecenas porttitor vestibulum pulvinar. Aenean sit amet viverra nulla. Curabitur cursus lacus ut dapibus malesuada. Sed efficitur nec nibh eget consectetur. Morbi aliquet auctor dui eu dictum. Etiam sodales, lacus ac ornare tincidunt, lectus nulla elementum odio, at convallis ante elit at tellus. Pellentesque bibendum facilisis metus at condimentum. Proin vel consequat est, eu auctor eros.

Ut risus sapien, lobortis at eleifend a, iaculis sed ex. Phasellus viverra, ante at eleifend feugiat, lacus massa interdum odio, sed rhoncus leo lectus id dolor. Nullam lacus nisi, mollis at eros at, fringilla aliquam enim. Morbi suscipit sed ante non mattis. Maecenas porta tortor in quam faucibus euismod. Nulla eget consequat augue, quis malesuada lectus. Praesent imperdiet orci id porta pellentesque. Donec tempus tristique ultrices. Maecenas ut imperdiet ipsum. Donec lobortis porta ante, eget cursus felis cursus sed. Nulla facilisi. Sed ut lacus in purus molestie sodales. Ut consectetur, lacus a viverra dictum, ipsum risus aliquam purus, sed tempor enim libero non est. Cras vitae nunc vitae lorem maximus euismod. Donec at hendrerit augue. Aliquam maximus condimentum velit, vel bibendum erat iaculis at.

Maecenas fermentum massa lorem, vel vulputate ipsum molestie eget. Nulla posuere lacus ut gravida dapibus. Praesent id tellus at neque vestibulum porttitor. Fusce nec tellus ut felis laoreet finibus. Etiam tristique lacus sit amet lorem hendrerit, non lobortis mauris vulputate. Phasellus eu congue urna. Vivamus ac ipsum quam. Duis justo ex, elementum sed dapibus at, varius vel lorem. Pellentesque in nibh eu ligula ullamcorper eleifend tristique eu risus. Cras eget mauris ac lacus posuere suscipit id id erat. Sed fringilla bibendum lacinia. Integer eget condimentum velit.

Donec et erat mi. Donec tempor rhoncus ornare. Nunc ut magna semper lectus fermentum vehicula. Suspendisse sit amet rutrum ante, eu convallis risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla nisl est, auctor eu sagittis id, blandit vitae purus. Pellentesque consectetur urna ac lacus semper, hendrerit semper justo fermentum. Cras euismod efficitur metus a suscipit. Suspendisse efficitur nibh mauris, vitae elementum enim facilisis eu. Maecenas ac ipsum lorem. Fusce nibh lacus, auctor non ipsum id, tempor euismod libero. Nulla bibendum tortor turpis, ac ultricies quam aliquet nec. Praesent ut eros sed augue porta congue sed eu ante. Nulla id porttitor ligula. Sed vestibulum nisl lectus, sed cursus leo dapibus ut.

Fusce auctor, neque eget tincidunt mattis, turpis lectus lobortis odio, et varius nibh lectus sit amet nulla. Phasellus at est tempus, dictum leo non, imperdiet nulla. Etiam rutrum nunc at pulvinar tristique. Sed imperdiet neque dolor, a accumsan risus vestibulum eget. Vestibulum non auctor mauris. Sed sit amet ipsum mi. Quisque rhoncus imperdiet tempus. Suspendisse in elementum dolor. Vivamus ut orci purus.

Pellentesque auctor elit vitae ante volutpat consectetur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean metus tellus, sagittis sit amet felis in, tincidunt varius tellus. Quisque dignissim vel quam id vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. In elementum metus sit amet tellus sagittis, et placerat mi viverra. Fusce rutrum purus in tristique cursus. Proin cursus tincidunt lacus, vel consectetur neque tempus nec. Pellentesque ullamcorper congue dolor at bibendum. Donec nec finibus felis. Sed aliquam est non mi accumsan, sed scelerisque orci commodo. Curabitur auctor pretium diam, vitae mollis metus tristique vitae. Donec auctor mollis justo ac auctor. Phasellus quis dignissim urna.

In sed dui ut nunc cursus dapibus id vel ligula. Mauris vel volutpat neque. Integer elementum consectetur euismod. Curabitur sed pulvinar purus, in pretium metus. Praesent consectetur sit amet ex suscipit porta. Phasellus dapibus sagittis turpis, at sagittis dolor pulvinar sit amet. Nunc at enim non massa euismod tempus nec vitae erat. Cras quis dui id mi fermentum pellentesque at ac tellus. Praesent eu pharetra metus. Morbi nec pretium nunc. Sed sed bibendum tellus. Aliquam porta tincidunt mi et tristique. Etiam eu ligula at nulla tincidunt egestas. Nam viverra enim sit amet eros porttitor lacinia. Mauris pulvinar justo in ultrices consequat.

Duis eu leo sit amet lacus pharetra venenatis sagittis at lacus. Sed cursus risus sit amet auctor eleifend. Aenean consequat elementum lorem in tristique. Duis vel venenatis purus. In vestibulum ante sed augue dictum rutrum. Vestibulum vestibulum dui vel ligula volutpat hendrerit. Praesent porttitor hendrerit nisi sed tempus. Quisque non elit sit amet nibh iaculis vulputate.

Curabitur scelerisque eros a risus tempus consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum blandit non est at laoreet. Duis ante nunc, commodo et maximus eget, volutpat quis magna. Mauris sed erat scelerisque, tincidunt tortor id, vehicula leo. Nullam sed felis urna. Nullam facilisis elementum rutrum. Curabitur mattis accumsan orci non dapibus. Cras in facilisis eros. Suspendisse fringilla nibh sit amet lorem tempor, vel porttitor sapien vehicula. Donec convallis odio dui, ut porttitor risus commodo a.

Aenean venenatis leo in dolor luctus vestibulum. Etiam non dui nec nibh dictum pretium. Donec at mauris iaculis, fermentum diam vel, vulputate ligula. Donec pellentesque lorem quis nibh tristique ultricies. Donec congue tempor lectus quis facilisis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut ut sagittis dolor. Nunc convallis ultricies ex, sed porttitor augue lobortis sit amet. Cras commodo venenatis vehicula. Integer volutpat nulla orci, eget dignissim nibh vestibulum eu. Morbi condimentum felis vitae hendrerit rhoncus. Morbi eleifend dui ut lorem egestas fermentum. Maecenas id arcu diam. Vivamus posuere purus ut quam pulvinar sollicitudin. Etiam porttitor consectetur sem, convallis aliquet urna volutpat ut. Morbi finibus nibh.

Generated 11 paragraphs, 1000 words, 6720 bytes of Lorem Ipsum
```

I use PuTTY with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate. The server I SSH into runs on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS x64.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work similarly in both cases on my side...

right click and Shift-insert both paste the entire text you quoted

"

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque cursus sed nibh sed ornare. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec vulputate lacus. Fusce vitae odio in nulla tempus maximus. Curabitur condimentum et augue sit amet laoreet. Fusce lobortis massa sed tellus vulputate, vel malesuada eros vulputate. Vivamus eu enim id sem tempor congue sit amet at eros. Pellentesque luctus enim libero, vel tristique tellus congue eget. Vivamus at nisl venenatis, commodo tellus a, varius purus. In vel dolor vitae nibh pharetra accumsan. Sed volutpat laoreet ipsum quis mattis.

Nulla eu purus justo. Sed massa dui, convallis eu elit vitae, maximus vehicula sem. Maecenas porttitor vestibulum pulvinar. Aenean sit amet viverra nulla. Curabitur cursus lacus ut dapibus malesuada. Sed efficitur nec nibh eget consectetur. Morbi aliquet auctor dui eu dictum. Etiam sodales, lacus ac ornare tincidunt, lectus nulla elementum odio, at convallis ante elit at tellus. Pellentesque bibendum facilisis metus at condimentum. Proin vel consequat est, eu auctor eros.

Ut risus sapien, lobortis at eleifend a, iaculis sed ex. Phasellus viverra, ante at eleifend feugiat, lacus massa interdum odio, sed rhoncus leo lectus id dolor. Nullam lacus nisi, mollis at eros at, fringilla aliquam enim. Morbi suscipit sed ante non mattis. Maecenas porta tortor in quam faucibus euismod. Nulla eget consequat augue, quis malesuada lectus. Praesent imperdiet orci id porta pellentesque. Donec tempus tristique ultrices. Maecenas ut imperdiet ipsum. Donec lobortis porta ante, eget cursus felis cursus sed. Nulla facilisi. Sed ut lacus in purus molestie sodales. Ut consectetur, lacus a viverra dictum, ipsum risus aliquam purus, sed tempor enim libero non est. Cras vitae nunc vitae lorem maximus euismod. Donec at hendrerit augue. Aliquam maximus condimentum velit, vel bibendum erat iaculis at.

Maecenas fermentum massa lorem, vel vulputate ipsum molestie eget. Nulla posuere lacus ut gravida dapibus. Praesent id tellus at neque vestibulum porttitor. Fusce nec tellus ut felis laoreet finibus. Etiam tristique lacus sit amet lorem hendrerit, non lobortis mauris vulputate. Phasellus eu congue urna. Vivamus ac ipsum quam. Duis justo ex, elementum sed dapibus at, varius vel lorem. Pellentesque in nibh eu ligula ullamcorper eleifend tristique eu risus. Cras eget mauris ac lacus posuere suscipit id id erat. Sed fringilla bibendum lacinia. Integer eget condimentum velit.

Donec et erat mi. Donec tempor rhoncus ornare. Nunc ut magna semper lectus fermentum vehicula. Suspendisse sit amet rutrum ante, eu convallis risus. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla nisl est, auctor eu sagittis id, blandit vitae purus. Pellentesque consectetur urna ac lacus semper, hendrerit semper justo fermentum. Cras euismod efficitur metus a suscipit. Suspendisse efficitur nibh mauris, vitae elementum enim facilisis eu. Maecenas ac ipsum lorem. Fusce nibh lacus, auctor non ipsum id, tempor euismod libero. Nulla bibendum tortor turpis, ac ultricies quam aliquet nec. Praesent ut eros sed augue porta congue sed eu ante. Nulla id porttitor ligula. Sed vestibulum nisl lectus, sed cursus leo dapibus ut.

Fusce auctor, neque eget tincidunt mattis, turpis lectus lobortis odio, et varius nibh lectus sit amet nulla. Phasellus at est tempus, dictum leo non, imperdiet nulla. Etiam rutrum nunc at pulvinar tristique. Sed imperdiet neque dolor, a accumsan risus vestibulum eget. Vestibulum non auctor mauris. Sed sit amet ipsum mi. Quisque rhoncus imperdiet tempus. Suspendisse in elementum dolor. Vivamus ut orci purus.

Pellentesque auctor elit vitae ante volutpat consectetur. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; Aenean metus tellus, sagittis sit amet felis in, tincidunt varius tellus. Quisque dignissim vel quam id vulputate. Aliquam erat volutpat. In elementum metus sit amet tellus sagittis, et placerat mi viverra. Fusce rutrum purus in tristique cursus. Proin cursus tincidunt lacus, vel consectetur neque tempus nec. Pellentesque ullamcorper congue dolor at bibendum. Donec nec finibus felis. Sed aliquam est non mi accumsan, sed scelerisque orci commodo. Curabitur auctor pretium diam, vitae mollis metus tristique vitae. Donec auctor mollis justo ac auctor. Phasellus quis dignissim urna.

In sed dui ut nunc cursus dapibus id vel ligula. Mauris vel volutpat neque. Integer elementum consectetur euismod. Curabitur sed pulvinar purus, in pretium metus. Praesent consectetur sit amet ex suscipit porta. Phasellus dapibus sagittis turpis, at sagittis dolor pulvinar sit amet. Nunc at enim non massa euismod tempus nec vitae erat. Cras quis dui id mi fermentum pellentesque at ac tellus. Praesent eu pharetra metus. Morbi nec pretium nunc. Sed sed bibendum tellus. Aliquam porta tincidunt mi et tristique. Etiam eu ligula at nulla tincidunt egestas. Nam viverra enim sit amet eros porttitor lacinia. Mauris pulvinar justo in ultrices consequat.

Duis eu leo sit amet lacus pharetra venenatis sagittis at lacus. Sed cursus risus sit amet auctor eleifend. Aenean consequat elementum lorem in tristique. Duis vel venenatis purus. In vestibulum ante sed augue dictum rutrum. Vestibulum vestibulum dui vel ligula volutpat hendrerit. Praesent porttitor hendrerit nisi sed tempus. Quisque non elit sit amet nibh iaculis vulputate.

Curabitur scelerisque eros a risus tempus consectetur. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum blandit non est at laoreet. Duis ante nunc, commodo et maximus eget, volutpat quis magna. Mauris sed erat scelerisque, tincidunt tortor id, vehicula leo. Nullam sed felis urna. Nullam facilisis elementum rutrum. Curabitur mattis accumsan orci non dapibus. Cras in facilisis eros. Suspendisse fringilla nibh sit amet lorem tempor, vel porttitor sapien vehicula. Donec convallis odio dui, ut porttitor risus commodo a.

Aenean venenatis leo in dolor luctus vestibulum. Etiam non dui nec nibh dictum pretium. Donec at mauris iaculis, fermentum diam vel, vulputate ligula. Donec pellentesque lorem quis nibh tristique ultricies. Donec congue tempor lectus quis facilisis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut ut sagittis dolor. Nunc convallis ultricies ex, sed porttitor augue lobortis sit amet. Cras commodo venenatis vehicula. Integer volutpat nulla orci, eget dignissim nibh vestibulum eu. Morbi condimentum felis vitae hendrerit rhoncus. Morbi eleifend dui ut lorem egestas fermentum. Maecenas id arcu diam. Vivamus posuere purus ut quam pulvinar sollicitudin. Etiam porttitor consectetur sem, convallis aliquet urna volutpat ut. Morbi finibus nibh.

Generated 11 paragraphs, 1000 words, 6720 bytes of Lorem Ipsum"
```

as a single block.